# rose wine vigorous bubbling after 10 days

Tags: wine

I made a demijohn of one gallon with a kit. It has been bubbling vigorously ten days later almost like a soft drink. I tested it with a hydrometer and no strength of alcohol showing. I was wondering what it may be and if I can cure with more sugar and yeast.

Comment: Can you add a picture and your ingredients / process? Thanks

Comment: Did you measure the original gravity with a hydrometer? If you want to know how fermentation is proceeding, you need to take period specific gravity measurements. If the gravity is going down, alcohol is being produced.

Answer (score 1):

If it has been bubbling for ten days, and smells OK, then likely you have wine. If it tastes like wine then good guess you have wine.

If it at first smells OK, then sip a little, if OK try a bit more. Usually there is nothing that your nose or tongue will not pick up that will harm you greatly.

With out pictures or more description it is hard to say anything else.

Also is this Rose or rosé wine, they are very different.